# Скорость выполнения запроса Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

EF6. Имеем запрос:

```
var changedDocs1 = (from d in nsql.Doc
                    //join c in nsql.Cnt on d.Receive equals c.NOwner
                    join ad in nsql.AlterationDoc.Where(x => x.AlterTime > localVersionDate) on d.NDoc equals ad.NDoc
                    join cep in
                        nsql.ChangeEndPeriod.Where(x => x.prev_Employee == eqEmployee && x.DateModific > localVersionDate) on
                        new { d.NDoc, d.Employee } equals new { cep.NDoc, Employee = cep.curr_Employee ?? -1 } into CEP
                    from cep in CEP.DefaultIfEmpty(null)
                    let deleteFlag = (!d.IsShipped || (cep != null && cep.curr_Employee != cep.prev_Employee)) ? true : false
                    where d.AccountDate == Date && (d.Employee == eqEmployee || cep != null)
                    select
                        new
                        {
                            d.NDoc,
                            Doc = d.Doc1 ?? -1,
                            NOwner = d.Receive,
                            d.Terms,
                            deleteFlag,
                            changeDate =
                                ad.AlterTime >= (cep == null ? ad.AlterTime : cep.DateModific)
                                    ? ad.AlterTime
                                    : (cep.DateModific ?? ad.AlterTime),
                            //c.Owner,
                            //c.DocAddress
                            Owner = "",
                            DocAddress = ""
                        }).ToList();
```

По логам смотрим сформированный запрос:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[NDoc] AS [NDoc], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Doc] IS NULL) THEN -1 ELSE [Extent1].[Doc] END AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[Receive] AS [Receive], 
    [Extent1].[Terms] AS [Terms], 
    CASE WHEN (([Extent1].[IsShipped] <> 1) OR (([Extent3].[Id] IS NOT NULL) AND ( NOT (([Extent3].[curr_Employee] = [Extent3].[prev_Employee]) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[curr_Employee] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = (CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[prev_Employee] IS NULL) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END)))))) THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END AS [C2], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[AlterTime] >= (CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[Id] IS NULL) THEN  CAST( [Extent2].[AlterTime] AS datetime2) ELSE [Extent3].[DateModific] END)) THEN [Extent2].[AlterTime] WHEN ([Extent3].[DateModific] IS NULL) THEN [Extent2].[AlterTime] ELSE [Extent3].[DateModific] END AS [C3], 
    N'' AS [C4], 
    N'' AS [C5]
    FROM   [dbo].[Doc] AS [Extent1] WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[AlterationDoc] AS [Extent2] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Extent1].[NDoc] = [Extent2].[NDoc]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ChangeEndPeriod] AS [Extent3] WITH (NOLOCK) ON ([Extent3].[prev_Employee] = @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent3].[DateModific] > @p__linq__2) AND ([Extent1].[NDoc] = [Extent3].[NDoc]) AND ([Extent1].[Employee] = (CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[curr_Employee] IS NULL) THEN -1 ELSE [Extent3].[curr_Employee] END))
    WHERE ([Extent2].[AlterTime] > @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[AccountDate] = @p__linq__3) AND (([Extent1].[Employee] = @p__linq__4) OR ([Extent3].[Id] IS NOT NULL))
```

Время выполнения этого запроса без каких либо изменений через SqlAdapter - 0.2 секунды.
Время выполнения через EntityFramework - 120 секунд.
Результаты выполнения одинаковы.

Что может служить причиной такой разницы?

UPD. Проблема локализована.
В какой-то момент SQL Server закэшировал крайне дурацкий план запроса. Запрос через EF его использовал, запрос через ADO - нет (по причине приведения типов параметров).
Добавление OPTION (RECOMPILE) решило проблему.

Comment: Параметры то получать ещё надо. Вы работаете не только с sql полями, но ещё и создаете анонимные классы. В итоге, это превращается в не совсем очевидные запросы плюс работу уже в памяти, скорее всего.

Comment: параметры - примитивы, два Int, 3 DateTime. Они определяются ранее. По логу видно, что они передаются в запрос.

Comment: Вот это "new { d.NDoc, d.Employee } equals new { cep.NDoc, Employee = cep.curr_Employee ?? -1 }" транслируется в sql?

Comment: Да,в условие left join'a: `AND ([Extent1].[NDoc] = [Extent3].[NDoc]) AND ([Extent1].[Employee] = (CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[curr_Employee] IS NULL) THEN -1 ELSE [Extent3].[curr_Employee] END))`

Comment: Действительно, запрос получился нормальным. Я бы полез профилировать. Вдруг проседает на чем то другом, а запрос реально за 0.2секунды и выполняется.

Comment: Вы измеряете время на прогретом контексте или вместе с инициализацией EF? У EF бывает очень долгая инициализация первого контекста.

Comment: На прогретом. Чуть раньше из этого же экземпляра идёт получение некоторых параметров, пары классификаторов - всё это работает вполне шустро.